# Why is file.read not returning the correct number of bytes?

Tags: python, c++, qt

I am trying to rewrite this python function in C++

```
def hash(name):
    readsize = 64 * 1024
    with open(name, 'rb') as f:
        size = os.path.getsize(name)
        data = f.read(readsize)
        f.seek(-readsize, os.SEEK_END)
        data += f.read(readsize)
    return hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
```

Here what I have tried.

```
void hash(QString name) {
    QFile file(name);
    long int readsize =  64 * 1024;  
    long int size = file.size();

    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        qDebug() << "coundn't open your file";
        return;
    }

    QByteArray data = file.read(readsize);
    file.seek(size - readsize);
    data += file.read(readsize);

    QString h = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(data, QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());
    return QCryptographicHash::hash(data, QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex();
}
```

Surprisingly this C++ function works but only when `readsize < 340-ish`. I'm can't tell why but with readsize bigger it doesn't even return the correct number of bytes (i'm expecting len(data) == 4*readsize at the end), the second `file.read`does not return the correct number of bytes.

Comment: What mode did you open the file when using C++?  The text mode may be translating the line ending character(s).  Try opening the file in binary mode.

Comment: `read` reads no more characters than you tell it to; it does not guarantee to read exactly the number you asked for.

Comment: ` QIODevice::Text` is the opposite of `'b'`  in `'rb'`, so you should REMOVE that, and the file will be treated as binary!

Comment: @AlanStokes I realize that. but if you look at my code, you'll see that I'm positioning the cursor so that I specifically have exactly `readline` ahead.